# how to specify version of python to run a script?

Tags: python

I'm learning python now using a mac which pre-installed python 2.7.5. But I have also installed the latest 3.4.

I know how to choose which interpreter to use in command line mode, ie python vs python 3 will bring up the respective interpreter.

But if I just write a python script with this header in it "#!/usr/bin/python" and make it executable, how can I force it to use 3.4 instead of 2.7.5?

As it stands, print sys.version says:

2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell a Python script to use a particular version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170827/how-do-i-tell-a-python-script-to-use-a-particular-version)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (script header) to the path to `python3.4` which you can get using [which](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_%28Unix%29).

For example, here's what do I have:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which python3.4
/usr/local/bin/python3.4
```

Then, just set the shebang appropriately:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.4
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe. A follow up if I may: when I do "which python3", I get "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3". Does that imply when I installed it, it got put in the wrong place? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @rockhammer well, you can make a symbolic link to it, e.g. `sudo ln -s  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3`.

Comment: Thanks, **shebang** was the key to find this: `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Answer (score 3):

You know, you can start python with `py -specific version` 
To run a script on interpreter with a specific version you'll just start your script with following parameters, `py yourscript.py -version`

Comment: Do you have some special environment? I've never heard of this, and I don't believe it is part of general Python.

Comment: This is specific to the anaconda environment

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the Python script a first line of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

It is better than setting the path or the exact python 3 sub version if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use:

```
py yourscript.py -version
```