# install python 3.7 via google colab as default python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I need to use **python3.7** as default python version to use in google colab(via [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AdEReIUyMABz2ELW-BpjW2k6B2-Yo_YJ?usp=sharing) ) for testing the [faceswap](https://github.com/deepfakes/faceswap) GitHub project, by this codes:

```
%cd "/content/faceit"
!rm -rf faceswap
!git clone  https://github.com/deepfakes/faceswap.git
%cd faceswap
!python setup.py
```

The reason is that,when i try to install [faceswap](https://github.com/deepfakes/faceswap) in google colab i get this error:

```
/content/faceit
Cloning into 'faceswap'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 7725, done.
remote: Total 7725 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 7725
Receiving objects: 100% (7725/7725), 194.20 MiB | 31.66 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5338/5338), done.
/content/faceit/faceswap
INFO    Running as Root/Admin
INFO    The tool provides tips for installation
        and installs required python packages
INFO    Setup in Linux 4.19.112+
INFO    Installed Python: 3.6.9 64bit
ERROR   Please run this script with Python version 3.7 or 3.8 64bit and try again.
```

So based of the different python module which needs to be installed by different files, it needs to install python 3.7 and set it as python default command.

I would appropriate, any help to solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775160/install-python-3-8-kernel-in-google-colaboratory), there are different ways to run a specific version of Python on Colab:

- Installing Anaconda
- Adding (fake) google.colab library
- Starting Jupyterlab
- Accessing it with ngrok

The code sample is below

```py
# install Anaconda3
!wget -qO ac.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh 
!bash ./ac.sh -b

# a fake google.colab library
!ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google \
       /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google

# start jupyterlab, which now has Python3 = 3.8
!nohup /root/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab --ip=0.0.0.0&

# access through ngrok, click the link
!pip install pyngrok -q
from pyngrok import ngrok
print(ngrok.connect(8888))
```

Additionally, I recommend you to use it by specifying the [Python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088338/how-to-specify-version-of-python-to-run-a-script?rq=1) to run a script on colab.

```
# Install the python version
!apt-get install python3.7

# Select the version
!python3.7 setup.py
```

You can see this example I have tried.

[image]

If you will use multiple library versions, you can also use [virtualenv on colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512569/is-it-possible-to-activate-virtualenv-in-google-colab-bin-sh-1-source-not) by specify the [python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20that%20will%20be,%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fpython3.) with `--python` option. For example:

```py
virtualenv env --python=python3.7
```