# How to install Python 3.7 in google colab?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, google-colaboratory, python-3.7

My google colab python version is 3.8 and I need version 3.7. I try to install python 3.7, but after installation I get an error to install packages.

I use this method to install python 3.7:

```
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
!sudo apt install python3-pip
```

After running the Python version is:

```
!python --version
#Python 3.7.15
```

When I want to install a package (for example, torchfold):

```
!pip install torchfold
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

I could not solve it with the available resources, can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63867581/install-python-3-7-via-google-colab-as-default-python)

Comment: Yes. But the package installation error continues

Comment: I have a same error. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: ```
!sudo apt install python3-pip
``` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940813/pip-no-module-named-internal

Comment: ``` !sudo apt install python3-pip ``` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940813/pip-no-module-named-internal

Answer (score 3):

```
-----To install specific version 3.7 of python in Google Colab-----
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3
/usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

## Select the specific number for 3.7

#Now check the version it will be 3.7

```
!python --version
```

#After that to install pip use these commands

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I used @M. Abdullah Fiaz but

-----To install specific version 3.7 of python in Google Colab-----

```
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3
/usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

In "!sudo update-alternatives --config python3" I was being asked:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.10   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.10   2         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.7    2         manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.8    1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: update-alternatives:
```

"
So I changed it to:

```
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3 <<< '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

After running `!sudo apt install python3-pip`, force a pip reinstall using: `!python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`
This is gonna ensure that pip is correct installed again.