# Python subprocess is running a different version of Python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to create a Python script to execute other Python scripts, and it works on most scripts, but will fail when it encounters `print('anything', end='')`.  This is because the subprocess is running 2.7, rather than 3.4.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to have the subprocess run 3.4.

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import subprocess
>>> sys.version
'3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]'
>>> results = subprocess.check_output('testprint.py', shell=True)
>>> results
b'2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]\r\n'
```

testprint.py is just this:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Edit: And of course I would realize a solution after posting the question.  I modified the code to the following:

```
path = r'C:\Python34\python.exe'
results = subprocess.check_output([path, 'testprint.py'], shell=True)
```

Now I'm passing in the executable path the script will be run through.  Still, I would love a more elegant and permanent solution.

Comment: I am not very experienced with that module but wonder if it is being directed to use 2.7...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170827/how-tell-python-script-to-use-particular-version

Comment: What is the behavior when running testprint.py from the command line without specifying the python executable to use?

Comment: I was going to suggest execfile, but then realized that got removed (though you could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357361/alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-2).

Comment: Huh, so if I run 'python testprint.py' I get 3.4 back.  But if I only say 'testprint.py' I get 2.7 back.

Comment: Don't use 'shell=True' unless it it needed because you are running a shell command instead of a file.

Comment: What you get when you 'run' a .py file without specifying a binary depends on which binary is currently associated with .py on your particular machine.  When you install a python version on Windows, there has been an option to 'make this python the default version'.  Part of the meaning of 'default version' is the version associated with .py.  Starting with 3.4.0 or later, .py is associated with py.exe, which unfortunately defaults to 2.7, unless you changed that as per the instructions hidden in the doc, or start your file with #! python x.  Better to specify the binary you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution is to do:

```
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'testprint.py'])
```

[`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.executable) is the location of the python binary running the code executing. Note that for some reason `shell=True` launches the python binary without any arguments on `sys.argv`, so either omit that option, use a string or [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote). This is effectively the same as your solution, but the executable position is not hard-coded.